# in css grid, how to make an element span only if next element is empty, without javascript

Tags: css, grid

I'm trying to create a template with my html elements, that would not be complicated if it was not for one constraint :

**the html elements have to be all siblings !**

indeed, I create them in the context of wordpress with divi builder, I have no possibility to create wrapper divs, unfortunately.

the template is the following :

```
 ---------------- -----------
| title 1        | img 1     |
|----------------|           |
| text 1         |           |
|                |           |
|                |           |
 ---------------- -----------
| title 2        |           |
|---------------- -----------|
| text 2                     |
|                            |
|                            |
 ---------------- -----------
| title 3        | img 3     |
|----------------|           |
| text 3         |           |
|                |           |
|                |           |
 ---------------- -----------
```

as you can see, if there is an image, it should be on the right of both the title and the text. If there is no image, the text should take all width.

In the post title i asked about span in css grid, but I actually don't care if it's in flex or with float or whatever, it's just that I don't suppose we can do it with something else than grid, since the image must be to the right of two elements and I cannot use divs to wrap them.

I'm looking for a css only solution, because I think it's too bad not to have a css solution if it exists.

Here is a code snippet with a js working solution, that consists in adding the span to the element if the img is missing :

```js
let imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.img');

imgs.forEach((img) => {
  let child_count = img.childElementCount;
  if (child_count === 0) {
    let next_text = img.nextElementSibling;
    next_text.classList.add('span-column');
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 700px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
}
.wrapper > * {
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
}
.title {
  grid-column: 1;
}
.img {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
}
.text {
  grid-column: 1;
}
.span-column {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title"><h2>title 1</h2></div>
  <div class="img"><img src="https://www.beatthebear.org/btb-bear.jpeg"></div>
  <div class="text"><p>Deleniti error quae rerum consequatur. Qui aut praesentium maiores non voluptatum et ullam corrupti. Commodi dolorum aut blanditiis quae non. Corrupti vitae aperiam dolorem debitis ut. Accusantium beatae sed et quisquam. Ipsa rerum qui ratione minus ad qui quaerat. Et molestias autem praesentium qui exercitationem in dolore. Facilis velit molestiae illum vitae consectetur doloremque quis voluptatem. Inventore necessitatibus facilis placeat magni est dolores eos veritatis. Laudantium aut sed voluptatem accusamus quo repellat. Ut vel aliquid commodi alias qui modi quo beatae. Consequatur nemo reprehenderit voluptas incidunt sequi a aut saepe. Enim quaerat temporibus aut autem aliquid. Consectetur qui et aspernatur recusandae. Veritatis eius laudantium et voluptatem et inventore. Hic culpa reprehenderit iusto ut qui. Voluptatem mollitia et excepturi qui sint nobis. Aut est magnam distinctio accusantium ea et. Sed sint maxime officia totam maiores. Ut voluptate iure facilis eveniet. Facilis sequi placeat natus voluptas. Ut numquam rem maiores est a cumque. Earum distinctio voluptas id.</p></div>
  <div class="title"><h2>title 2</h2></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="text"><p>Deleniti error quae rerum consequatur. Qui aut praesentium maiores non voluptatum et ullam corrupti. Commodi dolorum aut blanditiis quae non. Corrupti vitae aperiam dolorem debitis ut. Accusantium beatae sed et quisquam. Ipsa rerum qui ratione minus ad qui quaerat. Et molestias autem praesentium qui exercitationem in dolore. Facilis velit molestiae illum vitae consectetur doloremque quis voluptatem. Inventore necessitatibus facilis placeat magni est dolores eos veritatis. Laudantium aut sed voluptatem accusamus quo repellat. Ut vel aliquid commodi alias qui modi quo beatae. Consequatur nemo reprehenderit voluptas incidunt sequi a aut saepe. Enim quaerat temporibus aut autem aliquid. Consectetur qui et aspernatur recusandae. Veritatis eius laudantium et voluptatem et inventore. Hic culpa reprehenderit iusto ut qui. Voluptatem mollitia et excepturi qui sint nobis. Aut est magnam distinctio accusantium ea et. Sed sint maxime officia totam maiores. Ut voluptate iure facilis eveniet. Facilis sequi placeat natus voluptas. Ut numquam rem maiores est a cumque. Earum distinctio voluptas id.</p></div>
  <div class="title"><h2>title 3</h2></div>
  <div class="img"><img src="https://www.beatthebear.org/btb-bear.jpeg"></div>
  <div class="text"><p>Deleniti error quae rerum consequatur. Qui aut praesentium maiores non voluptatum et ullam corrupti. Commodi dolorum aut blanditiis quae non. Corrupti vitae aperiam dolorem debitis ut. Accusantium beatae sed et quisquam. Ipsa rerum qui ratione minus ad qui quaerat. Et molestias autem praesentium qui exercitationem in dolore. Facilis velit molestiae illum vitae consectetur doloremque quis voluptatem. Inventore necessitatibus facilis placeat magni est dolores eos veritatis. Laudantium aut sed voluptatem accusamus quo repellat. Ut vel aliquid commodi alias qui modi quo beatae. Consequatur nemo reprehenderit voluptas incidunt sequi a aut saepe. Enim quaerat temporibus aut autem aliquid. Consectetur qui et aspernatur recusandae. Veritatis eius laudantium et voluptatem et inventore. Hic culpa reprehenderit iusto ut qui. Voluptatem mollitia et excepturi qui sint nobis. Aut est magnam distinctio accusantium ea et. Sed sint maxime officia totam maiores. Ut voluptate iure facilis eveniet. Facilis sequi placeat natus voluptas. Ut numquam rem maiores est a cumque. Earum distinctio voluptas id.</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these selectors below, and make sure `.img` is fully empty, not even a whitespace.

```
.wrapper .img:empty + .text {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}
```

Comment: cool :) I actually didn't pay enough attention, and the images have a span around them, so i have to use `.wrapper .img:has(span:empty) + .text`, but I'm worried that `:has` is to fresh to be used in production... And even `:empty` seems a little fragile for production purpose, since I don't choose how divi creates the elements

Comment: It depends on your requirements, but they are safe to use nowadays [empty](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Aempty) and [has](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas)

Comment: @hugogogo if you are going to use has() then better do `.wrapper .img:not(:has(img)) + .text` and you don't have to care about white space or extra wrapper

Comment: @TemaniAfif that's a good idea !

Comment: That's smart @TemaniAfif the whole thing looks pretty long lol

Comment: Just realized you're good to use any of those selectors @hugogogo since you're using css grid already

Comment: @Stickers i'm not sure what you mean ? but if it's because [grid](https://caniuse.com/css-grid) is recent, it was fully implemented in 2017, whereas [:has](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas) was only in 2022, so i feel like it's more safe. Anyway, i decided to use it, since the layout still work when the text don't span

Comment: If you still have concern over :has I'd suggest update the markup i.e [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kesa6t5r/) you can then even use flexbox @hugogogo

Comment: @Stickers yes but here you have created divs around groups of elements, it's just what i cannot do, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

:empty and :has are your friends

```
.wrapper {
  max-width: 700px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
}
.wrapper > * {
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
}
.title {
  grid-column: 1;
}
/*
.title:has(+.img:empty) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
*/
.img {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
}
.img:empty {
  display: none;
}
.text {
  grid-column: 1;
}
.img:empty+.text {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
.span-column {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}
```

Comment: cool :) I didn't see your answer ! nice trick with the title ! As I wrote in another comment, I'm not sure it is safe to use `:empty` when I don't choose how divi will create the elements, and I don't know if i can already use `:has` because the people that will use the website are not a category of people that will have recent browser for sure...

Comment: Well then you have to choose. If your site is going to appear broken to most of your users if you go with the CSS solution, then you'll have to go with your Javascript solution.

Comment: yes, I'll think about it, it's not that broken when it's not spanned, so maybe I'll go with the css solution now that i have it :)

Comment: :has is the css positive lookahead. You can give it any selector. That includes [attr] to search for any element with attr as an attribute, hint hint ;)

Comment: If you wanna toy around a bit: Browsers now support nested selectors [MDN: Nesting Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Nesting_selector)

Comment: @BenC. I didn't know this :) It looks a little bit like sass